# Laravel Storage link is not working in Hostinger Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, symlink, laravel-artisan

I've hosted my Laravel 7 website on Hostinger shared hosting. I use this route `Route::get('/linkstorage', function() { Artisan::call('storage:link'); });`
to link my storage folder `public_html/storage` with `public_html/public/storage`

But the link which is generated say's "Directory not found".

**Directory /public_html/public//home/u907022978/domains/saifkhalilhardware.com/public_html/storage/app/public not found**

I also tried using the below symlink, but it also did not work.

```
$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public_html/storage/app/public';
$linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public_html/public/storage';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
```

Please suggest how I can connect my storage link.

Regards,

[here's the image which shows the project's structure] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKTvc.png)

Comment: I think your hosting setup is not correct. You should set up Laravel by putting all your project under saifkhalilhardware.com and putting the contents of `public` under `public_html` and then (in a service provider probably) do `app()->instance('path.public', base_path('public_html'));` the way you are setting this up now is not secure. Also make sure `storage/app/public` actually exists.

Comment: @apokryfos I've uploaded my project on Hostinger using Git. The project is placed on a root directory like `saifkhalilhardware.com/public_html` but the problem is with the shortcut storage folder link, which is generated after the `Artisan::call('storage:link');' command.

I've added the screenshot of file structure in the question, please also check that.

Comment: From the screenshot your `storage` directory seems to be empty. It should match the structure from [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/9.x/storage)

Comment: @apokryfos I just check the storage directory and verify the structure that's all fine. Problem seems to be in this link. can you check this link, why this link has **/public_html/public/** and also a double slash `"//"` after that? I think this is causing the problem.  I'm not sure why a link like this is generating here.`/public_html/public//home/u907022978/domains/dappergroupofcompanies.com/public_html/storage/app/public`

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar error with the some commands in the terminal:

```
chmod -R o+x /home/user_hosting/repositories/project/storage
chmod -R o+x /home/user_hosting/repositories/project/public
```